# I want to hide the current window, when click on Login button

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am using an Existing  Authentication dll in an Excel Add In created using  Excel DNA. Now problem here is that in my Autentcation dll my code contains Application.current Window
but in case of Excel i dont have any window.

When I execute application, login window pop ups and on login button click I want hide login window but its not working in Excel DNA.

My code is as below :

```
   if (Application.Current != null && Application.Current.Windows.Count > 0)
    Application.Current.Windows[Application.Current.Windows.Count - 1].Hide();
    Form form = new Form();
    form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Why are you using a Form in WPF?

Comment: Confusing about tags used in your question and your code?! Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Bind a bool property to  the form's visibility

[BoolVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Changing the value of the bool property in the Login eventhandler will do the trick.